# Square Root Code C++ without sqrt()

Tags: c++

I have to create a code where the user inputs a number which is a perfect square, and I have to show its root. I've made this code, but I'm getting `Segmentation Fault 11` , in this piece: `int j = squareRootVector[i];
squareRoot.push_back(j);`. 
I can't change the code too much, so is there a way that I can do that?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


int main() {

cout <<

 "Enter the number:\n";

    int input;
    int number = input;
    int divider = 2;
    vector<int> squareRootVector;
    vector<int> squareRoot;

    cin >> number;

    for(int divider = 2; number > 1; divider++) {
        while((number % divider) == 0) {
            number /= divider;
            cout << number << endl;
            squareRootVector.push_back(divider); 
        }
    }


    for(int i = 0; i < squareRootVector.size(); i++) {
        cout << squareRootVector[i] << " ";

        /*******PROBLEM*******/
        if(squareRootVector[i] == squareRootVector[i+1]) {
            int j = squareRootVector[i];
            squareRoot.push_back(j);
        }
        /*********************/
    }

    int root;

    for (int i = 0; squareRoot.size(); i++) {
        root = root * squareRoot[i];
    }

    cout << "Square Root of " << input << " is: " << root << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suspect the problem is here: `squareRootVector[i+1]`. Since `i` is the last element of the vector, `i+1` is out of bounds

Comment: `squareRootVector[i+1]` is out of bounds for `i == size()-1`

Comment: After you will fix this problem (on which you already got some proposal), you should also be careful about variable `input` which is not initialized. It is supposed to remember user input, so you should better read the input in it (`cin >> input`), and then assign the value to `number` (which seems to be a working variable in your algorithm). I think the code will be clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers, guys. I've ended up with this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


int main() {

cout << "Enter the number:\n";

int input = 0;
int number = 0;
cin >> input;
number = input;
int divider = 2;
vector<int> squareRootVector;
vector<int> squareRoot;



for(int divider = 2; number > 1; divider++) {
    while((number % divider) == 0) {
        number /= divider;
        squareRootVector.push_back(divider); 
    }
}

int vectorSize = squareRootVector.size() - 1;


for(int i = 0; i < vectorSize; i++) {
    if(squareRootVector[i] == squareRootVector[i+1]) {
        int j = squareRootVector[i];
        squareRoot.push_back(j);
    }
}

int root = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < squareRoot.size(); i++) {
    root = root * squareRoot[i];
}

cout << "Square Root of " << input << " is " << root << endl;


return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour on accessing `squareRootVector[i+1]` with `i` just one below `size` (which your loop constaint allows) is *undefined*.

Consider writing

```
for (std::size_t i = 1; i < squareRootVector.size(); i++) {
```

instead, and rebasing the `for` loop body accordingly. I've also slipped in a change of type for `i`.

Answer (score 1):

Shortly, the problem is that the last cycle in the last "for":

```
for(int i = 0; i < squareRootVector.size(); i++)
```

has the following line in it:

```
squareRootVector[i] == squareRootVector[i+1];
```

This is an "out of limits" error: `squareRootVector` only has `squareRootVector.size()` elements (let's say `n`), and the elements are indexed from `0` to `n-1`.

`squareRootVector[i+1]` in the last cycle points one element *after* the last one of `squareRootVector`, which is undefined behavior.

Comment: "one element after the end" is misleading because usually it is `end` that points to one past the last element

Comment: So if I add `if( (i+1) < squareRootVector.size())` before `if(squareRootVector[i] == squareRootVector[i+1])` it should work, no?

Comment: @tobi303: the "end()" points to past the last element. I was literally talking about the end.

Dudi: It wouldn't crash.

Comment: @CalinCeteras I took on me to slightly edit your answer, feel free to rollback it.

Comment: in c++ "end" literally refers to one past the last element. Saying `array[i+1]` is one past the end is confusing

Answer (score 0):

Using vector::iterator is proper way.

```
for(vector<int>::iterator it = squareRootVector.begin(); it != squareRootVector.end(); ++it)
{
    if( (it+1) == squareRootVector.end() )
    {
        //what to do if there's no next member???
        break;
    }

    if( *it == *(it+1) )
    {
        squareRoot.push_back(*it);
    }
}
```